# How to serialize a nested sortable ul list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

based on this exmaple, i trie to serialize the list, but the built-in function of jquery-ui seem only support one level.

Is it possible to catch the other elements, too?

```
   <ul class="sortable">
      <li id="link-1">Foo!
        <ul class="sortable">
          <li id="link-2">FooFoo!
            <ul class="sortable"></ul>
          </li>
          <li id="link-3">FooBar!
            <ul class="sortable"></ul>
          </li>
          <li id="link-4">FooBaz!
            <ul class="sortable"></ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="link-6">Bar!
        <ul class="sortable"></ul>
      </li>
      <li id="link-7">Baz!
        <ul class="sortable"></ul>
      </li>
```

javascript:

```
$(function () {
      $('ul.sortable').sortable({
        connectWith: 'ul.sortable',
        placeholder: 'placeholder',
        update: function (event, ui) {
            var result = $(".sortable").sortable().sortable("serialize");
            alert("result: "+result);
      }).disableSelection();
});
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/KenPowers/pen/zxIcB

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think you have an extra bit here: `$(".sortable").sortable().sortable("serialize");`

Comment: sorry i cannot see the difference!? on top, in the meantime i think i could not work in this way, reset the order is not possible with this IDs, i think the Ids has to change for sub-folders!?

Comment: There are some syntax errors in your code as well, you're  missing some closing brackets and closing tags. Sortable is working as expected, it's giving you the serialization of that specific list. You will have to build a custom function to serialize the entire list and child lists together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.sortable').sortable({
    connectWith: '.sortable',
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    update: function(event, ui) {
      var struct = [];
      var i = 0;
      $(".sortable").each(function(ind, el) {
        struct[ind] = {
          index: i,
          class: $(el).attr("class"),
          count: $(el).children().length,
          parent: $(el).parent().is("li") ? $(el).parent().attr("id") : "",
          parentIndex: $(el).parent().is("li") ? $(el).parent().index() : "",
          array: $(el).sortable("toArray"),
          serial: $(el).sortable("serialize")
        };
        i++;
      });
      console.log("Structure", struct);
      var iArr = [];
      var iSer = [];
      $(".sortable:eq(0) li").each(function(ind, el) {
        var label = $(el).attr("id");
        iArr.push(label);
        var pre = label.slice(0, label.indexOf("-")) + "[]=";
        iSer.push(pre + label.slice(label.indexOf("-") + 1));
        if ($(el).children().eq(0).is("ul")) {
          $(el).find("li").each(function() {
            iArr.push($(this).attr("id"));
            iSer.push(pre + $(this).attr("id").slice(label.indexOf("-") + 1));
          });
        }
      });
      console.log("Items Array", iArr);
      console.log("Items Serial", iSer.join("&"));
    }
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul class="sortable">
  <li id="link-1">Foo!
    <ul class="sortable">
      <li id="link-2">FooFoo!
        <ul class="sortable"></ul>
      </li>
      <li id="link-3">FooBar!
        <ul class="sortable"></ul>
      </li>
      <li id="link-4">FooBaz!
        <ul class="sortable"></ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="link-6">Bar!
    <ul class="sortable"></ul>
  </li>
  <li id="link-7">Baz!
    <ul class="sortable"></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This will iterate over each `<li>` element and build an Array and Serialized result. It will look for a single child elements, and if it exists will place those items in line with the rest, as if all the items were in one list.

Hope that helps.

Comment: great, it helps a lot and make many thinks easier to understand. How i can restore the tree with the generated "structure" if i save this in a db? Is there a kind of "restore-function" for sortable?

Comment: @caro these questions seem way above and beyond your post. Please provide more detail to your post, with examples, and can update my answer.

Comment: If i change my post to the current situation, noone can see my first post to know what was my problem/question - or did i missunderstand you? Based on your code i want do a ajax call to save the the structure in db (may i have to serialize them?). If its done i need a function to reset the tree if the page will refresh.

Comment: If my post answered your question, then mark it. If you have another situation, can post another question with proper example and details.

Comment: ok, i understand the way :-) Ive create a new question, could you have a look please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193761/how-to-restore-a-jquery-ui-sortable-list-by-using-stored-structure-from-db