# How to restore a jquery ui sortable list by using stored structure from db

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I've tried to store a list-structure in my db (based on this question  [1]: [How to serialize a nested sortable ul list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54185616/how-to-serialize-a-nested-sortable-ul-list/54187707?noredirect=1#comment95214170_54187707)) and after that I need a way to restore/reset the list if the page is refreshed or load new based on the data from db.

**Is there a build-in way to do this or how can I do that?**

In my list, I use nested elements to support the way to create flexible nested structure.

This is what I already have

The list

```html
<ul id="mysite" class="mysite editor-ul ui-sortable-handle ui-sortable">
  <li class="draggable editor-li editor-li-head ui-sortable-handle">Headline</li>
  <li class="draggable editor-li ui-sortable-handle" id="p-1">
    Item1
    <ul class="mysite editor-ul ui-sortable"></ul>
  </li>
  <li class="draggable editor-li ui-sortable-handle" id="p-5">
    Item 2
    <ul class="mysite editor-ul ui-sortable">
      <li class="draggable editor-li ui-sortable-handle" id="p-7" style="">
        Item 3
        <ul class="mysite editor-ul ui-sortable"></ul>
      </li>
      <li class="draggable editor-li ui-sortable-handle" id="p-6" style="">
        Item 4
        <ul class="mysite editor-ul ui-sortable"></ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The JS Code

```js
$(function() {
  //$(".mysite").sortable({

  $(".mysite").sortable({
    connectWith: ".mysite",
    placeholder: "placeholder",
    update: function(event, ui) {
      var struct = [];
      var i = 0;

      $(".mysite").each(function(ind, el) {
        struct[ind] = {
          index: i,
          class: $(el).attr("class"),
          count: $(el).children().length,
          parent: $(el).parent().is("li") ? $(el).parent().attr("id") : "",
          parentIndex: $(el).parent().is("li") ? $(el).parent().index() : "",
          array: $(el).sortable("toArray"),
          serial: $(el).sortable("serialize")
        };
        i++;
      });
      console.log("Structure", struct);


      $.ajax({
        data: {
          "'.$this->security->get_csrf_token_name().'": "'.$this->security->get_csrf_hash().'",
          "job": "updateSiteStruc",
          "data": struct
        },
        type: "POST",
        url: "'.base_url().'"
      });


      var iArr = [];
      var iSer = [];
      $(".mysite:eq(0) li").each(function(ind, el) {

        if ($(el).attr("id") != undefined) {
          var label = $(el).attr("id");
        } else {
          return true;
        }

        iArr.push(label);
        var pre = label.slice(0, label.indexOf("-")) + "[]=";
        iSer.push(pre + label.slice(label.indexOf("-") + 1));
        if ($(el).children().eq(0).is("ul")) {
          $(el).find("li").each(function() {
            iArr.push($(this).attr("id"));
            iSer.push(pre + $(this).attr("id").slice(label.indexOf("-") + 1));
          });
        }
      });
      console.log("Items Array", iArr);
      console.log("Items Serial", iSer.join("&"));
    }
  }).disableSelection();

});
```

Based on this I store the structure

- send by ajax
- save `json_encode($post['data'])` in db

So now I have in my db

> "[{"array": ["", "p-1", "p-5"], "class": "mysite editor-ul ui-sortable-handle ui-sortable", "count": "3", "index": "0", "parent": "", "serial": "p[]=1&p[]=5", "parentIndex": ""}, {"class": "mysite editor-ul ui-sortable", "count": "0", "index": "1", "parent": "p-1", "serial": "", "parentIndex": "1"}, {"array": ["p-7", "p-6"], "class": "mysite editor-ul ui-sortable", "count": "2", "index": "2", "parent": "p-5", "serial": "p[]=7&p[]=6", "parentIndex": "2"}, {"class": "mysite editor-ul ui-sortable", "count": "0", "index": "3", "parent": "p-7", "serial": "", "parentIndex": "0"}, {"class": "mysite editor-ul ui-sortable", "count": "0", "index": "4", "parent": "p-6", "serial": "", "parentIndex": "1"}]"

Formatted version of string above:

```js
"[{
  "array": ["", "p-1", "p-5"],
  "class": "mysite editor-ul ui-sortable-handle ui-sortable",
  "count": "3",
  "index": "0",
  "parent": "",
  "serial": "p[]=1&p[]=5",
  "parentIndex": ""
}, {
  "class": "mysite editor-ul ui-sortable",
  "count": "0",
  "index": "1",
  "parent": "p-1",
  "serial": "",
  "parentIndex": "1"
}, {
  "array": ["p-7", "p-6"],
  "class": "mysite editor-ul ui-sortable",
  "count": "2",
  "index": "2",
  "parent": "p-5",
  "serial": "p[]=7&p[]=6",
  "parentIndex": "2"
}, {
  "class": "mysite editor-ul ui-sortable",
  "count": "0",
  "index": "3",
  "parent": "p-7",
  "serial": "",
  "parentIndex": "0"
}, {
  "class": "mysite editor-ul ui-sortable",
  "count": "0",
  "index": "4",
  "parent": "p-6",
  "serial": "",
  "parentIndex": "1"
}]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to construct a list of items that can be stored as a string in a DB and then built out as `<ul>` in HTML, I would suggest using much more complex structure so you can have a deeper relationship within the data.

```js
$(function() {

  var saveData;

  function makeObj(list) {
    var d = [];
    d.push({
      id: list.attr("id"),
      class: list.attr("class"),
      items: []
    });
    list.children("li").each(function(ind, el) {
      var item = {
        attr: {
          index: ind,
          id: $(el).attr('id') || "list-item-" + ind,
          class: $(el).attr('class'),
          style: $(el).attr('style')
        },
        label: el.firstChild.data.trim(),
        children: $("ul", el).length ? true : false,
        childObj: false
      };
      d[0].items.push(item);
    });
    return d;
  }

  function buildList(d, t) {
    console.log(d);
    $.each(d, function(key, item) {
      $("<li>", item.attr).html(item.label).appendTo(t);
    });
  }

  function makeSort(obj, cnwt) {
    obj.sortable({
      connectWith: cnwt,
      placeholder: "placeholder"
    });
  }

  function stringify(d) {
    return JSON.stringify(d);
  }

  function parse(s) {
    return JSON.parse(s);
  }

  $("#saveList").click(function(e) {
    var myData = makeObj($("#mySite"));
    console.log(myData);
    $.each(myData[0].items, function(key, item) {
      if (item.children) {
        myData[0].items[key].childObj = makeObj($("ul:eq(0) > li:eq(" + key + ") > ul"));
      }
    });
    console.log(stringify(myData));
    saveData = stringify(myData);
  });

  $("#loadList").click(function(e) {
    if (saveData.length) {
      console.log(saveData);
      var myData = parse(saveData);
      var newList = $("<ul>", {
        id: myData[0].id,
        class: myData[0].class
      }).insertAfter($(this));
      buildList(myData[0].items, newList);
      makeSort(newList, myData[0].class);
      $.each(myData[0].items, function(key, item) {
        if (item.children) {
          var sList = $("<ul>", {
            id: item.childObj[0].id || "",
            class: item.childObj[0].class
          }).appendTo($("li:eq(" + item.attr.index + ")", newList));
          buildList(item.childObj[0].items, sList);
          makeSort(sList, item.childObj[0].class);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul id="mySite" class="mysite editor-ul">
  <li class="draggable editor-li editor-li-head">Headline</li>
  <li class="draggable editor-li" id="p-1">Item1
    <ul class="mysite editor-ul"></ul>
  </li>
  <li class="draggable editor-li" id="p-5">Item 2
    <ul class="mysite editor-ul">
      <li class="draggable editor-li" id="p-7" style="">Item 3
        <ul class="mysite editor-ul"></ul>
      </li>
      <li class="draggable editor-li" id="p-6" style="">Item 4
        <ul class="mysite editor-ul"></ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="saveList">Save</button>
<button id="loadList">Load</button>
```

The above example is specific to show the save and load features. To test, click Save and then click Load. The structure is saved to an string and placed in a variable. Then in load, it is read from the string and builds a new copy.

This is less about the sortable and more about the saving and loading. You can use `stringify(makeObj())` in `update` to send the data to your DB. If your list is deeper, you will have to repeat the `makeObj()` a few times for each layer.

The same goes when you get the data from the DB. Either it will come back as a string where you can use `parse()` or it will come back as an object. This would be the case if you use PHP to `encode_json()` and send JSON data directly back to the script.

Sending back String:

```
buildList(parse(data), $(".target"));
```

Sending back JSON:

```
buildList(data, $(".target"));
```

As you can see, it can get pretty complex. It might be better to find a plugin that can do the heavy work for you. Remember this is just one example and maybe not the best one for what you're doing.

Hope that helps.